# Spring Security denies access to `@Secured` method in spite of granted authorities

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, vaadin

So I have a Vaadin (8) view that I've `@Secure`d for Spring Security:

```
@Secured(SUPERADMIN_ROLE)
@SpringView(name = AdminHomeView.NAME)
class AdminHomeView : DemoViewWithLabel(){
    companion object {
        const val NAME = "admin/home"
    }

    override val labelContent = "This is the protected admin section. You are authenticated and authorized."
}
```

where `DemoViewWithLabel` is just a very simple abstract class displaying

```
VerticalLayout(Label(labelContent))
```

So if I log in as somebody with the `Superadmin` role, I can access this view just fine.

However, let's make a minor change and override a method ...

```
@Secured(SUPERADMIN_ROLE)
@SpringView(name = AdminHomeView.NAME)
class AdminHomeView : DemoViewWithLabel(){
    companion object {
        const val NAME = "admin/home"
    }

    override val labelContent = "This is the protected admin section. You are authenticated and authorized."

    override fun enter(event: ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent?) {
        super.enter(event)
    }
}
```

THIS gets me an `AccessDeniedException` ... and I don't understand why.

So I turned on debug loggign for Spring Security, and this is what it had to say:

```
Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public void ch.cypherk.myapp.ui.views.admin.AdminHomeView.enter(com.vaadin.navigator.ViewChangeListener$ViewChangeEvent);
  target is of class [ch.cypherk.myapp.ui.views.admin.AdminHomeView];
  Attributes: [Superadmin]
```

```
Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@a6801701:
  Principal: ch.cypherk.myapp.model.auth.MyUserDetails@6e4c5c5b;
  Credentials: [PROTECTED];
  Authenticated: true; Details: null;
  Granted Authorities: RIGHT_MANAGER, Superadmin
```

This seems ok, so far. It expects a `Superadmin` authority and it has an authenticated user with that `Superadmin` authority.

However ...

```
Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@7ddc2dd1, returned: 0  
Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@75d3fbb7, returned: 0  
Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@391740fc, returned: 0
```

and consequently,

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AbstractAccessDecisionManager.checkAllowIfAllAbstainDecisions(AbstractAccessDecisionManager.java:70)
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at ch.cypherk.myapp.ui.views.admin.AdminHomeView$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae16a97c_4.enter(<generated>)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.performNavigateTo(Navigator.java:778)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.lambda$navigateTo$9a874efd$1(Navigator.java:702)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.ViewBeforeLeaveEvent.navigate(ViewBeforeLeaveEvent.java:54)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.View.beforeLeave(View.java:79)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.runAfterLeaveConfirmation(Navigator.java:730)
    at com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo(Navigator.java:701)
  at ...
```

WHY?!!

Would appreciate some help in resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In a Nutshell**

The authorities granted do not exhibit the `ROLE_`-prefix and therefore get ignored by the `RoleVoter`.

Replacing the `RoleVoter` with a custom implementation that has an empty prefix solved the issue.

**Full Story**

Now this leaves the question why we could access the view at all. The explanation is simple but requires a bit more context.

We're working on migrating a Thorntail application to Spring Boot.

And we're using Vaadin 8 (because we have legacy Vaadin 7 stuff that we haven't managed to get rid of yet and need to support).

And so?

Vaadin is a single-page framework and Vaadin 8 has this nasty way of referencing views, namely, it uses a `#!` on the root url (e.g. `https://<host>:<port>/#!foo/bar/baz/...`).

Nothing after `#` is sent to the server, which means we cannot differentiate between an access to `/` and an access to `/#!foo/bar/baz/...`

As such, we cannot use Spring Security to guard accesses to views.

AND we have a Vaadin view that we need to allow unauthenticated access to.

As a consequence, we were forced to allow unauthenticated accesses to `/`. The `MainUI` (that handles all the incoming requests) would check if the user is authenticated and redirect to a login page if they were not.

Access to the views themselves is guarded by Vaadin, not Spring. The `SpringViewProvider` will not find a `View` to which a user is not supposed to have access to (as a consequence, the user cannot navigate there).

However, as soon as we *call* a method on that view, Spring security kicks in and performs the access checks. It is *these* checks that failed because the authorites granted did not have the "ROLE_"-prefix Spring expected. (I had assumed this was just a convention, but it's not; the `RoleVoter` actually ignores authorities that do not exhibit the prefix, so you HAVE to do it that way, OR you have to provide your own `RoleVoter`.)

The solution was relatively straightforward...

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    securedEnabled = true,
    prePostEnabled = true,
    proxyTargetClass = true
)
class GlobalSecurityConfiguration : GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration(){
    override fun accessDecisionManager(): AccessDecisionManager {
        return (super.accessDecisionManager() as AffirmativeBased).apply {
            decisionVoters.replaceAll {
                when(it){
                    is RoleVoter -> MyRoleVoter()
                    else -> it
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where

```
class MyRoleVoter : RoleVoter(){
    init {
        rolePrefix = ""
    }
}
```